# jQuery - Get Dynamic (*) Element By Id and put on array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm working to create a classifieds site. On the search page will be presented multiple products cards. Each product card can have more than one image. When that happens, I will uses a slider.

To build this slider, I'm using a jquery library (bxslider). The application is based on WordPress.

So far, everything was going well. Cards and slider working. But when I have more than one card (post), the slider controls change the position on all cards. Of course, since the selector is the same for everyone.

Then I added the post ID to the ID selector, making every single card. But now must do jQuery understand that there are several unique cards for him to apply the function that creates the slides within each card.

My PHP Code

```
<?php 
    $id = get_the_ID(); 
?>
<div id="card-slider-<?php echo $id?>">
    <?php 
        $images = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vdw_gallery_id', true); 
        foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
            <li>
                <div class="card-slide-item">
                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $image, 'imob-thumbs' ); ?>">
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php }
    ?>
</div>

<div class="card-slide-prev"></div>
<div class="card-slide-next"></div>
```

My jQuery

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.sliderID = function() {
        var sliders = [];
        sliders = $('[idˆ=card-slider-]').length;
        console.log('sliders ids', sliders);
    };
})( jQuery );

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.sliderID();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving each slider an individual id `card-slider-{id}`, consider to give them all a common class `card-slider` and initiate the slider plugin on all elements that have that class. You can pass along the ids of the prev/next selectors (which you can e.g. store in a data attribute) in the initialization arguments of the slider:

**Slider initiation**

```
$( ".card-slider" ).each(function( index ) {
    var slider_id = $(this).data('id');
    $( this ).bxSlider({
        nextSelector: '#card-slide-'+slider_id+'-next',
        prevSelector: '#card-slide-'+slider_id+'-prev',
    });
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<?php 
    $id = get_the_ID(); 
?>
<div class="card-slider" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <?php 
        $images = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vdw_gallery_id', true); 
        foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
            <li>
                <div class="card-slide-item">
                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $image, 'imob-thumbs' ); ?>">
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php }
    ?>
</div>

<div id="card-slide-<?php echo $id; ?>-prev"></div>
<div id="card-slide-<?php echo $id; ?>-next"></div>
```

Comment: Xphan, first, thank you for your collaboration. Your code work, with this, the problem is the same: the prev and next selectors control the slide in all product cards. If I get the ID I can put the ID in the #card-slider and also in the prev and next selectors (.card-slide-prev and .card-slide-next)

Comment: Please see my edited answer. You can pass along the IDs of the slider navigation in the initialization arguments.

Comment: Xphan, works fine! I will look closely your code to learn the concept. Thanks for sharing your knowledge and help people.